# Wi-Fi Access point loses internet when installing Docker

Tags: network-manager, docker, wireless-access-point

I have an Ubuntu 22.04 that I use as a Wireless Access Point. After installing Docker all devices connected to the WAP lost internet.

After reading some posts I changed the NetworkManager.conf, to not managed the docker bridge:

```
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=interface-name:docker0;
```

however the issue persists.

On a device using the WAP I noticed that I can use nslookup without issues, but when I trace the route it gives me this output:

```
1   3 ms   2 ms   4 ms   myUbuntuServer [10.42.0.1]
2   *      *      *      Request timed out
```

Without docker installed it gives me:

```
1    3 ms   2 ms   4 ms   myUbuntuServer [10.42.0.1]
2   12 ms   8 ms   3 ms   myRouter [192.168.1.1]
```

So when docker is installed the WAP network is not reaching the wired network. Can someone help me, please?

Ps: after removing Docker, WAP works perfectly, but that's not what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was the issue. Docker writes to the iptables file and despite not having iptables running as service the configuration is valid and the packets were being dropped by iptables.
I did the configuration as described in this post: https://serverfault.com/questions/431593/iptables-forwarding-between-two-interface and it worked